# icon is moving out of the anchor tag

Tags: html, css

```css
#branding h1 {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 10px;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  color: black;
}

.hom {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

a:active {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

a.log {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
}

a img {
  display: inline-block;
  top: 17px;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="branding">
      <h1> Web Design </h1>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="hom">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.google.com" target="blank">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="log">
            <img src="log.png" style="width:30px; height:20px;"> Log In</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

In the link, I am trying to put login icon by using the image tag but somehow it is moving out of the link, I am just trying to keep the icon inside to **login** text but after floating it to *right *, it is going out of the flow. [image: Output Screenshot]

So Do I need to use bootstrap or we can achieve the expected output using pure CSS

Answer (score 1):

The issue is you are using `float:right` in the `<img>` tag which take the image out of the parent flow..So remove `float:right` and reverse your HTML markup(*icon will come after text*).

As you are using font-awesome...no need to use image here....Use

```
<i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i>
```

***Stack Snippet***

```css
#branding h1 {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 10px;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  color: black;
  display: block;
}

.hom {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

a:active {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

a.log {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="branding">
      <h1> Web Design </h1>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="hom">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.google.com" target="blank">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="log">Log In <i class="fa fa-sign-out"></i></a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this.

```css
#branding h1{
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
}
nav{
  float:right;
}
nav ul li{
  display:inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin:10px;
}

nav ul li a{
  text-decoration:none;
  position:relative;
  top:5px;
  border:2px solid red;
  padding:10px;
  color:black;

}
.hom{
  background-color:red;
  color:white;
}   
nav ul li a:hover{
  background-color: red;
  color:white;
}
a:active{
  background-color: blue;
  color:white;
}

a.log{

  background-color:red;
  color:white;
  border-radius:5px;
  margin:5px;
  position:relative;
  width:auto;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <meta name="description" content="web design affordable">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title></title>
      <style>

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <div id="branding">
          <h1> Web Design </h1>
        </div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="hom">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.google.com"target="blank">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="log">
              Log In<img src="log.png" style="width:30px;height:20px;position: relative;top: 5px;margin-left: 10px;"></a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </header>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will be helpful to you

```css
#branding h1{
  float:left;
  display:inline-block;
}
nav{
  float:right;
}
nav ul li{
  display:inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin:10px;
}

nav ul li a{
  text-decoration:none;
  position:relative;
  top:5px;
  border:2px solid red;
  padding:10px;
  color:black;

}
.hom{
  background-color:red;
  color:white;
}   
nav ul li a:hover{
  background-color: red;
  color:white;
}
a:active{
  background-color: blue;
  color:white;
}

a.log{

  background-color:red;
  color:white;
  border-radius:5px;
  margin:5px;
  position:relative;
  width:auto;



}
a img{
  display:inline-block;
  top:17px;
  position:relative;
  float:right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <meta name="description" content="web design affordable">
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title></title>
      <style>

    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <div class="container">
        <div id="branding">
          <h1> Web Design </h1>
        </div>
        <nav>
          <ul>
            <li><a href="#" class="hom">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="https://www.google.com"target="blank">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
            <li><a href="#" class="log" style="display:inline-block">
              <img src="log.png" style="width:30px; height:20px;top: 0px; 
   margin-left: 5px;"> Log In</a></li>
            </ul>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </header>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just delete this

```
a img {
display: inline-block;
top: 17px;
position: relative;
float: right;
}
```

Try this [working link](https://jsfiddle.net/0bcj2xnu/). 
if you want to use the image as button icon.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```css
#branding h1 {
  float: left;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav {
  float: right;
}

nav ul li {
  display: inline-block;
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 10px;
}

nav ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  position: relative;
  top: 5px;
  border: 2px solid red;
  padding: 10px;
  color: black;
}

.hom {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

nav ul li a:hover {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

a:active {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

a.log {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin: 5px;
  position: relative;
  width: auto;
  display: block;
}

a img {
  display: inline-block;
  top: 0;
  position: relative;
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <div id="branding">
      <h1> Web Design </h1>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#" class="hom">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="https://www.google.com" target="blank">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" class="log">
            <img src="log.png" style="width:30px; height:20px;"> Log In</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>
</header>
```